# Moving OSs from 1TB to 2TB

Tags: linux, windows, operating-systems, gpt, nvme

I have a 1TB nvme drive with windows and linux installed. The partitions look like this:

[partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40CvB.png)

Now I would like to move both these operating systems to a 2TB nvme. How do I do this without reinstalling anything? I would like each OS to have 1TB of storage.

Comment: I'd attempt a bit copy of the disk (eg using dd or better ddrescue when its unmounted), then use gparted to move and resize.   Have you considered an alternative of keeping your 2 current partitions in the first TB and creating a third partition with shared storage available to both OS's?  This would mean you don't need to move/resize anything as well...

Comment: What have you tried? How you duplicate a disk is well documented so where are you stuck extra?

Answer (score 0):

Clone drive with OSFClone then use GParted to repartition drive.

Keep source drive as a backup in case it all goes pear shaped.